# Is it insect repellent "mats", "tablets" or "mat tablets?

Tags: terminology

Is it insect repellent "mats", "tablets" or "mat tablets? I have found all of the above three versions during my [search](https://www.google.com/search?ei=lVJWX7HvDOWS0PEP1KyH4AI&q=insect+repellent+mats+vs+tablets&oq=insect+repellent+mats+vs+tablets&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAM6BAgAEEc6BAgeEApQqvRiWK2FY2COwGNoAHABeACAAbYFiAGdE5IBCTItNC4yLjAuMZgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp).

Comment: Either mats or rablets will do.

Comment: If  you are translating, be careful as these repellent devices use either replaceable mats or tablets. The reason you get mat tablet is due to key word "confusion".

Comment: You know these kinds of questions are difficult to answer and it would be nice if you would make a choice or at least weigh in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Thermacell seems to be the main company that makes this type of device.

There is a mat with repellent in it, which is replaceable:

This fuel-powered Thermacell technology uses heat activated repellent to create an invisible, scent-free, zone of protection from mosquitoes. The devices are powered by a small fuel cartridge that provides the cordless, portable heat that is directed to a metal grill. **A small mat saturated with repellent is inserted on top of the metal grill. Heat disperses the repellent from the mat into the air, creating the zone of protection**.

In some brands, **there are tablets placed into a device.**

[thermacell repellents](https://www.thermacell.com/pages/how-it-works#)

2. Here is a **device that uses tablets which you place in the device:**

[image: tablets in a device]

Conclusion: Either you have a mat or a tablet, both of which can be replaced depending on the device you decide to use.

Comment: Thank you all for your detailed explanations !